# How to protect bearer tokens in a web app

Tags: rest, oauth-2.0

I am trying to implement the Authorization Code flow described in [RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.1) (OAuth 2.0) for a JavaScript-based application.  I understand that I should use a web server back-end as a confidential client so that it can protect the access token and refresh token returned by the authorization server and not pass them on to the JavaScript front-end.  Then all requests from the front-end to any protected resources go via the web server back-end, which attaches the access token to the request and proxies it on.

My question is how do I let the JavaScript front-end make use of these tokens in a secure way?  I assume that I have to do something like set up a session on the web server and pass back a cookie that identifies the session.  But this means that the JavaScript application then has a cookie that gives them the same privileges as if they just had direct access to the bearer tokens stored in the web server.  How does having a web server to hold the tokens give extra security?

Comment: Do you have to use the Authorization code flow or did you just choose it?

Comment: I need to support refresh tokens and [section 4.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-4.2) of the spec says that the implicit grant type does not support them.

Answer (score 0):

> I understand that I should use a web server back-end as a confidential client so that it can protect the access token and refresh token returned by the authorization server and not pass them on to the JavaScript front-end.

No, it is a misunderstanding of the OAuth2 flows and goals.

**Here is the OAuth2 main goal**: your application (which can for instance be a JavaScript program running in the browser, a web server, both, etc.) **MUST NOT** need to know the user's credentials (most of the time a login/password pair) to access the service on behalf of the user.

**Here is the way OAuth2 must be used to achieve this goal**:

- according to your needs, that is having a Javascript-based application running in the browser (i.e. **not** a node.js application), you need to use the OAuth2 **implicit flow**, not the authorization code flow. But of course, because your application is running in the browser, it will not be able to persist the credentials to access the resource offered by the service provider. The user will have to authenticate to the service provider for each new session on your application.
- when your application needs to access the service provider when the user is not logged in, or when your application is able to persist credentials (because your application has its own credential system to identify its users), your application does not only rely on a JavaScript program running in the browser. It may rely only on a web server, or on both a web server and a JavaScript program that talks to this server. So, in those cases, you must use the **authorization code flow**.

**So, as a conclusion, you have decided to add a web server to your application because you thought you had to use the authorization code flow. But in your case, you probably do not have to use this code flow, therefore you should select the appropriate code flow for your application: implicit code flow.** And this way, you do not have to add a web server to run your application.

> How does having a web server to hold the tokens give extra security?

This does not give extra security. Having a web server to hold the tokens is simply a way to let your application access the service on behalf of the user, in the background, when the user is not logged on your application.

Comment: But the OP wants to use refresh tokens, which the implicit flow doesn't support. In this case, I think his app would need its own web-server session, protected by its own set of credentials, so it can securely store the tokens on the server. This would seem to remove the benefit of using OAuth2 to delegate the authentication process, since you'd first need a separate authentication process for the session. Or am I mistaken?

Answer (score 0):

While I agree with Alexandre Fenyo's comments, I just want to add the 2021 version. You should no longer be using the `implicit flow` as this is [no longer considered secure](https://developer.okta.com/blog/2019/05/01/is-the-oauth-implicit-flow-dead).

For scenarios such as this where a JavaScript application has to handle tokens I would suggest using the `Authorization Code flow with PKCE` instead: https://auth0.com/docs/flows/authorization-code-flow-with-proof-key-for-code-exchange-pkce